# Spring Boot Starter Data JPA - liquibase error

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to create a postgres DB using the JPA starter from spring boot. I have a simple entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
data class Project(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
    val owner: String,
    val language: Language,

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long? = null,
    val description: String? = null,

    @ElementCollection
    val tags: List<String> = listOf(),
    val license: String? = null
)

enum class Language {
    KOTLIN, JAVASCRIPT, JAVA
}
```

And I have this in my application.properties

```
logging.level.com.project=DEBUG
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

my gradle file for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: "kotlin-jpa"
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$spring_boot_version")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$spring_boot_version")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgres_version")
}
```

When Igo to run the server, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration':
```

But Im not using liquibase? The expected behaviour should be that spring generates my table in postgresql

Answer (score 0):

fixed with adding

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

to the config